# IIS 10 ARR FARM Only Hits Second Server

Tags: iis, arr

Trying to learn IIS farming on Server 2016 - IIS 10,i'm able to configure farm setup but my ARR only get hits from second server all the time.

Here re my configuration details;
Main Server
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.15 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it only contains one page as index.asp;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 001</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='red' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 001</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Second Server ;
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.16 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it contains the same asp page as index.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 002</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='BLUE' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 002</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Third Server ;
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.17 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it contains the same asp page as index.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 003</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='GREEN' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 003</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are main server settings;
[FARM SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR6kr.png)
[URL RE WRITE SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msg4L.png)
[LOAD BALANCE SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4QG.png)
[BROWSER OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDVLN.png)

After these settings when i call 192.168.2.15 it hits to 192.168.2.16/index.asp and it's only show this page
[BROWSER OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDVLN.png)
it never shows other two pages from two servers.

Refreshed page with shift+F5 multiple times, cleared browser and server's cache, no matter what i do it only shows page on Web Server 002/192.168.2.16 and never hits to main server/192.168.2.15 or third server/192.168.2.17.

On the almost all how to documents on the web, they are using domain instead of LAN IP addresses, is that what i am doing wrong? I'm working on local network that's why should i edit the hosts files of the servers and clients to work with domains? Does ARR requires at least 3 servers(main server for farm configuration +2 servers for balance) to work properly?

Comment: In the screenshot of the ARR config it looks like there is only one server configured?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist yeah you are right,it was when i get screenshot but after that i've added other servers but it didn't change anything.